# FOSUserBundle/Symfony3: Check current password before changing it

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using Symfony3 and FOSUserBundle.

I am trying to create an action which will allow my users to change their password when they are already logged in.

I am asking them to input their OLD password and new the NEW desired password and I want to check is the OLD password is the same with the password currently on record.

For some bizarre reason the encoder keeps on returning the wrong hash. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $newPasswordPlain = 'newpassword';
    $currentPasswordForValidation = 'test';

    $encoder_service = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
    $encoder = $encoder_service->getEncoder($user);
    $encodedPassword = $encoder->encodePassword($currentPasswordForValidation, $user->getSalt());

    var_dump( $encodedPassword);
    var_dump( $user->getPassword());

    if ( $user->getPassword() == $encodedPassword ) {
        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $user->setPlainPassword($newPasswordPlain);
        $userManager->updateUser($user, true);
    } else {
        var_dump('error: not the same password'); exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of "encodePassword", which generates a new password hash. You need to use "isPasswordValid" to check if the current password matches the current password hash. There is a difference between encoding a new and validating an existing.

Reference: [How to check if a username/password combination is valid for FOS UserBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180912/how-to-check-if-a-username-password-combination-is-valid-for-fos-userbundle)